# Magento Inventory Reservation Compensation command not working

Tags: magento2.3.0, inventory, reservations

I have tried to run the following command to compensate for the inventory reservation.

```
bin/magento inventory:reservation:create-compensations -r
```

But it got stuck, as in the below image.

[image]

It would be very helpful if anyone has a solution to this issue.

Comment: I am trying to run this command because of this  issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26095

Answer (score 5):

This command is waiting for you to tell it what compensation to create. See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/inventory-cli-reference.html for more detail, but generally, what you want to do after truncating the `inventory_reservations` table is to pipe the output of list-inconsistencies into create-compensations:

```
bin/magento inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies -r | bin/magento inventory:reservation:create-compensations
```

However, if you have a 3rd party manually modifying orders or qty directly in the database, then you need to turn off MSI because it can't track what it doesn't know about.

Answer (score -1):

You can truncate `inventory_reservation` table it will resolve your issue.

You can find more details here. 
https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/2046

The one always take backup before performing direct SQL :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I need a permanent solution to this issue. It is not practical to truncate the table as I am getting average of 100 orders daily.

Comment: If you follow order process then it will not create issue for you. Weird count is due to some order havent been completed and MSI reserved those qty once order placed. As this is for dev environment you shouldn't execute this in production. For permanent solution you can cancel orders which needs to be if you cant then it will start behaving weird in production as well.

Comment: I have truncated the inventory_reservation table two times. After that also issue recurred. That's why I posted the question.